# /say command (how to name the command block)

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to have a command block named the same as the nearest player. I t tried naming it @p, but when I ran the command, it stayed [@p] (message). What should I do?

Comment: To the close vote reviewers: If you think it's unclear what the question is (which I disagree with), look at the answer, it should make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make the command block say a command as if the closest player is saying it, you should use the `/execute` command.

It's really simple. What the command does is that it executes the command on behalf of an entity. The specific command you're looking for looks like this:

```
/execute @p ~ ~ ~ say <message>
```

If the nearest player's name is Dragonmaster, and the message you want to say is "Hello, world!", then the chat message will look like this:

> [Dragonmaster] Hello, world!

Comment: Thank you! I’m very bad at commands so everyone that answers my questions are a great help.

Answer (score 0):

You must set the 'hover note' on the command block to name it. (This currently works only in Bedrock Edition)